# Gulp task to copy folder into build folder give empty folder

Tags: javascript, gulp, directory

So i have built my own module and am trying to make a gulp task to copy the folder into my build folder. When this happens, nothing inside the folder is created in my build folder, it is just an empty folder.

My gulp task:

```
gulp.task("MyModule", function() {
    return gulp.src("MyModule")
        .pipe(chmod(777))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.build.node_modules));
});
```

paths.build.node_modules resolves to: build/node_modules
MyModule is in the root of the application folder.

Any reason why it would just be copying the folder and nothing inside of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not instructing it to copy the contents of the folder.

try `gulp.src(["MyModule", "MyModule/**/*"], base:{'.'})` to copy the folder and everything in it instead of just the folder.

Comment: Thank you, that is closer. But that only copies the files inside the folder to the location and not the folder.

Comment: That's because it's not instructed to copy the folder :) you can provide multiple paths like this `gulp.src(['path/one', 'path/two'])`

Comment: How do i specify that it should put path 2 inside of path one? Or else I will have the files and the empty folder int he same directory and not the files inside of the folder.

Comment: you can set a base directory for the output: see the options.base section in the gulp documentation https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md

Comment: Cool, I got it to work by simply doing gulp.src(paths.MyModule.root + "/**/*", {base: '.'}) If you add the base part to your answer i'll mark it as accepted. Thank you again.

Comment: @Nick3306 cleaned up my answer. Glad you got it working!